# Using mpirun installed on a compute node, with PBS

Tags: mpi, hpc, pbs

I'm trying to get a code to run in parallel using `mpirun`, in the PBS queue. The script I'm using is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=4 
#PBS -l walltime=4:10:00
#PBS -N job
#PBS -j oe

/usr/bin/mpirun -np 4 a.out
```

where `a.out` is the executable. The problem is that the `mpirun` I'm using is the one on the main node of the cluster. I want to use an `mpirun` installed on my own compute nodes, which is also in /usr/bin/mpirun.

I tried just copying `mpirun` in the folder and running with the line

```
./mpirun -np 4 hello.out
```

and that worked for some simple "hello world" program, but it doesn't work for the more complex code. It also works from my compute node if I just type

```
/usr/bin/mpirun -np 4 a.out
```

How do I use the `mpirun` of the compute node in the PBS script? I simply cannot use the stuff on the main node because it's an old linux version I'm not ready to change.

Comment: How do you run the script? Do you simply send it to the queue with `qsub script.sh`?

Comment: Your explanation suggests you either have to cross-compile your application (so it can run on the compute nodes) or have at least an ABI compatible MPI on both nodes. Did you already take care of that ?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov I ran the script just as you said. I don't know how to make it pick the right `mpirun`, which is the one installed on the node.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I compiled it so it can only run on compute nodes. -- I'm not sure what ABI compatible MPI means.

Comment: try adding `which mpirun` in your script, it should point to `/usr/bin/mpirun`, if not, simply `/usr/bin/mpirun a.out` in your PBS script, and then `qsub` it.